# Smartsheet download attachment via Python

Tags: python, api, smartsheet-api

I'm using the simple-smartsheet library for read data from a sheet in Smartsheet and download existing attachments on each row of the sheet.

I can already read the data for each row, however I cannot download existing attachments.

```
import config
from simple_smartsheet import Smartsheet

sheet = smartsheet.sheets.get(id=config.SHEET_ID) 
for row in sheet.rows:
    attachments = row.attachments
    print(attachments)
```

when executing the above command I get as a result:

```
[]
```

**[simple-smartsheet](https://pypi.org/project/simple-smartsheet/)**

I use the simple-smartsheet library as it is the only one that supports python versions 3.6+

**my python version 3.7.5**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that library has not implemented logic for dealing with the attachments yet.

as an alternative to solving this problem I implemented a solution with the code below:

```
import requests


#token = 'Your smartsheet Token'
#sheetId = 'Your sheet id'

r = requests.get('https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/{sheetId}/rows/{rowId}/attachments', headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'})

response_json = r.json()

print(response_json)
```

see [Get Attachments](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-attachment) for more details on handling attachments Smartsheets

Comment: Do you know how to download the attachments as files?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [list_row_attachments](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#list-row-attachments) to find information of the attachments that belongs to a row.

The code might look like this:

```
import config
from simple_smartsheet import Smartsheet

sheet = smartsheet.sheets.get(id=config.SHEET_ID) 
for row in sheet.rows:
    response = smartsheet_client.Attachments.list_row_attachments(
        config.SHEET_ID,
        row.id,
        include_all=True
    )
    attachments = response.data
    print(attachments)
```

Answer (score 1):

my solution is not very pythonic, but works, it consist of 2 steps

1. Get the attachment links
2. Save the file to a local HDD (I'm doing backups too) as a pivot place

**1.** to get the list of attachments:

```
    import smartsheet
    import urllib.request    
    smart = smartsheet.Smartsheet()
    att_list = smart.Attachments.list_all_attachments(<sheet_id>, include_all=True)
```

**2.** Downloading the attachments to local disk, you need to create a loop to go through the list of attachments, you can also add your own conditions to discriminate which ones to download:

```
    for attach in att_list:
        att_id = attach.id  #get the id of the attachment
        att_name = attach.name  # get the name of the attachment
        retrieve_att = smart.Attachments.get_attachment(<sheet id>, att_id)  #downloads the atachment
        dest_dir = "C:\\path\\to\\folder\\"
        dest_file = destd+str(att_name)  # parsing the destination path
        dwnld_url = retrieve_att.url # this link gives you access to download the file for about 5 to 10 min. before expire
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(dwnld_url, dest_file) ## retrieving attachement and saving locally
```

Now you have the file and you can do whatever you need with it